# Indexing unique values in array using the FREQUENCY formula in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, frequency

I am trying return unique values from a third column if the values on the first and the second column match. I have been able to get the array formula below to work:

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384,SMALL(IF(C$3:W$3=Funding!$J4:$J3385, ROW(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")}

However when I try to insert the FREQUENCY function I get an error:

{=IFERROR(INDEX(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384,SMALL(IF(C$3:W$3=Funding!$J3:$J3384, ROW(FREQUENCY(Funding!$A$3:$A$3384,Funding!$A$3:$A$3384)),ROW(1:1)-1),1)),"")}

**Column A**  **Column B**  **Column C**  **Column D**
     11            1             1            **11**
     22            1             1            **22** 
     33            3             3            **33**
     44            7             0
     55            5             0
     66            5             0

Answer (score 0):

If I had 50 reputation points, I would comment and ask, but these formulas are not exactly the same.  Did you select a different cell for the second example?

```
Funding!$J4:$J3385
```

Also, you have the same range in data array and bins array in your frequency formula.

What error did you receive?